# How to redirect after the subscription payment is completed in Razorpay using JS?

Tags: javascript, redirect, razorpay

```
<form>
    <script src="https://cdn.razorpay.com/static/widget/subscription-button.js"      
            data-subscription_button_id="*********" 
            data-button_theme="rzp-dark-standard" async>
        if (typeof response.razorpay_payment_id == 'undefined' || 
            response.razorpay_payment_id < 1) 
        {
            redirect_url = 'https://www.google.com/';
        } 
        else 
        {
            redirect_url = 'https://in.search.yahoo.com/?fr2=inr';
        }
        location.href = redirect_url;
    </script> 
</form>
```

This is the `Razorpay` subscription form.

This does not work to redirect.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure, if this is the only problem you are facing, but if the `<script>` tag has the `src` attribute, browsers should ignore the content between `<script>` and `</script>`.

Try this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>script example</title></head>
<body>
<script src="a.js">
 console.log("inside");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

while a.js contains:

```
console.log("from a.js");
```

This produces only `from a.js` output in the console. Removing the `src` attribute from `<script>` tag produces `inside` output in the console.